# Iterate through class members in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I would like to know what is the best approach in order to iterate through the members of a class in Objective-C. I want to do this so when the class changes I don't have to rewrite a method that checks some of the class members.

I.e:

```
@Interface Foo : NSObject
{
    NSString *bar1;
    NSString *bar2;
}
```

So I want to dinamically retrieve bar1 and bar2 here.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you just referring to properties here?

Comment: Yes, to be more accurate, all the instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, given that properties and other class members can be of (radically) different types, is a Bad Idea™.

A better approach is likely to group the members you are interested together in a solitary `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` property, and iterate over that when you need to access this group of similar members.

A second approach is to have a static array of key strings in the class you are doing the checking with, containing the accessor keys for the relevant class members; and iterating over that, using the fact that `@property`s are Key-Value Coding compliant, allowing you to use `-valueForKey:` and `-setValue:forKey:` in lieu of their actual accessors.

This does of course require updating the generation of that array when changing the class; so that may or may not be acceptable for your use.

Comment: How about using the `- (NSArray *)attributeKeys` in the `NSObject` class ?

Comment: @Francisco: You *could* do that, yes. But if you are planning on adding a bundle of string keys, that *really* isn't the best way of going about it. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: I wanna get all the `NSString` variables and check they are right. It is likely that some variables will be either added or removed, and I wanna make sure it keeps working.

Comment: @Francisco: In order to do this, they must at the very least all be properties; instance variables won't do. But again; because it's kind of important: I really think you want to use an `NSDictionary` property here.

Comment: @Francisco Sevillano: There is no such thing as “all the `NSString` variables” (or properties). Objective-C's static typing is only for your benefit when compiling the program; after that point, everything is `id`: A variable or property that holds an object can hold any object, and nothing is known at run time about what kind of object you meant it to hold.

Comment: @Williham Totland No I don't. First I don't want to have to change the dictionary every time the class changes. I wanted something that would work automatically. And second  I think its kind of ugly to have a dictionary that contains the names of all the properties. That is called repetitive information and in my opinion that is very prone to errors.

Comment: @Francisco: Right you are, but that isn't what I suggested. What I suggested was to *store* the properties in the dictionary, and not as instance variables at all.

Comment: @Peter Hosey But how about using `isKindOfClass:` to find out if its a `NSString` at run time?

Comment: @Williham Totland All right then! I guess I could do that. But you know, I would change an important class within my application just for the sake of too little funcionality. I don't think it is worth it. But thanks for explaining yourself anyway.

Comment: @Francisco Sevillano: That will work only for variables/properties that have values. Those that contain `nil` will fail that test. You will also get a false positive for any variable or property that can contain any object and contains a string at that moment, or that accidentally contains a string (e.g., because of an over-release).

Comment: @Peter Hosey: Technically, [nil isKindOfClass:AnyClass]; will give the right answer.

Comment: @Williham Totland: Indeed: The right answer to the wrong question. ☺

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are after [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)